# when I make logout, Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I get this error when I make logout.

the part below is the auth condititon.

error

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
in Query (at auth.js:8)
in Unknown (at App.js:29)
```

auth.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import { GET_ACTIVE_ADMIN } from "../queries";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const auth = condition => Component => props => (

  <Query query={GET_ACTIVE_ADMIN}>
    {({ data, loading }) => {
      if (loading) return <div>Loading</div>;
      return condition(data) ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />;
    }}
  </Query>
);

export default auth;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether the component is unmounted or not. You can achieve this by two ways:

1. setting `this._unmounted` flag and check over it.
2. Use `useRef()`, in your case this will work fine for functional
   component and Hook.

**Code:**

```
function CustomComponent() {

     const isMountedRef = useRef(null);
    
     useEffect(() => {
        isMountedRef.current = true;
        if(isMountedRef.current){
              //  axios call or dispatch events here
         }
    
      return () => isMountedRef.current = false;
      }
    
    return (
        <div> //Return Values /<di>
    }
```

Alterantively ,You can try with this library: [Unmounted](https://github.com/iShawnWang/withUnmounted)